# How to execute a function right after state gets updated with Hooks in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

As my trivial experience in Javascript and React Native, I've been struggling with how to execute a function call `checkValidDate` right after my state for the dates have been updated.

I'm using [react-native-modal-date-time-picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) to choose the date.

Here's my code:

```
  const [chosenStartDate, setChosenStartDate] = useState('');
  const [chosenStartDate_unix, setChosenStartDate_unix] = useState(null);
  const [chosenEndDate, setChosenEndDate] = useState('');
  const [chosenEndDate_unix, setChosenEndDate_unix] = useState(null);

  const handleConfirm = (day) => { 

    hideDatePicker(); // Set isDatePickerVisible to false

    if(chosenMode){ // If true, calendar shows up for choosing starting date, false --> for choosing ending date
      setChosenStartDate(moment(day).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
      setChosenStartDate_unix(parseInt((new Date(moment(day).format()).getTime())/60000));
      // Convert date to epoch time
    }else{
      setChosenEndDate(moment(day).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
      setChosenEndDate_unix(parseInt((new Date(moment(day).format()).getTime())/60000));
      checkValidDate(chosenStartDate_unix,chosenEndDate_unix)
      // --> I know that the dates only get updated after the handleConfirm has been executed
      // --> So basically, the chosenEndDate_unix passed in checkValidDate at this moment is still
      // null. Therefore, I can't check it correctly
    }

  };

  const checkValidDate = (start, end) => {
    console.log('Checking')
    console.log('chosenEndDate_unix', chosenEndDate_unix);
    console.log('chosenStartDate_unix', chosenStartDate_unix);
    if(start && end){
      ((end - start) >= 5) 
      ? (console.log('VALID'))
      : (alert('Please travel aleast 5 minutes, life is worth explored!'), setChosenEndDate(''))
    }
  }

  //...
  return(
    //...
    {isDatePickerVisible && (
              <DateTimePickerModal
                isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
                mode={mode}
                onConfirm={(day)  => {
                  handleConfirm(day)
                  // I tried to execute the checkValidDate here, but it also doesn't work 
                }}
                onCancel={hideDatePicker}
              />
            )}
  )
```

Basically, I have 2 buttons.

- One for choosing a `startDate` which doesn't need to be checked.
- Another for choosing an `endDate` which needs to be checked whether It's longer that `startDate` for at least 5 minutes or not
- When pressing `startDate` button, `chosenMode` will be set to `true` and vice versa for `endDate` button
- `handleConfirm` is the function we'll execute when we press the `OK` button on the calendar. As designed in `react-native-modal-date-time-picker`, only when we press `OK` will the date chosen be passed to the `onConfirm` prop

How can we execute the `checkValidDate` right after the `chosenEndDate` and `chosenEndDate_unix` has been updated?

**PLEASE HELP ME**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much Yupeng Li. Thank to your suggestion I've come up with the solution

By the way, when we place 2 dependencies which will change at the same time like that. checkValidDate() will be executed twice. So we'll put only 1 dependency which is `chosenEndDate_unix`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!chosenMode) checkValidDate(chosenStartDate_unix, chosenEndDate_unix)
  }, [chosenEndDate_unix])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect`. The checkValiddate is called when chosenEndDate or chosenEndDate_unix changed.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    checkValiddate()
}, [chosenEndDate, chosenEndDate_unix]);
```

The official document has more info of how it works: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects